# Impala unable to read Dateless timestamp from Parquet file

Tags: time, timestamp, parquet, impala, cloudera-cdh

Impala v2.11.0+ (CDH v5.11.1+) cannot read timestamps with only a time value from Parquet file.

```
create table TT2(t timestamp) STORED AS PARQUET;
insert into TT2 (t) values ("10:00:00");
select * from TT2;
+------+
| t    |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
WARNINGS: Parquet file 'hdfs://localhost:20500/test-warehouse/tt2/714d741212df3180-cd4e670800000000_226739479_data.0.parq' column 't' contains an out of range timestamp. The valid date range is 1400-01-01..9999-12-31.`
```

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-5942

Even though the select statement returns null, the metastore manager shows that the column has the value

> 4714-12-30 10:00:00.0

What I'm looking for is an alternative way to query this data to get the time value instead of manually finding and converting all the dateless timestamp columns to string.

I've tried

`SELECT cast(t as string) FROM TT2`

`SELECT date_part('hour', t) FROM TT2`

`SELECT from_timestamp(tms, "HH:mm:ss") FROM TT2`

`SELECT extract(tms, "hour") FROM TT2`

`SELECT extract(cast(tms as string), "hour") FROM TT2`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that since you are interested in only the time part so I would suggest to simply replace the date part with some acceptable date and then impala provides functions to extact time from timestamp (all your further queries on top of data can make use of it), so I think one possible solution is

1)Create a temporary table where timestamp column is string

2)Now you will get the value like "4714-12-30 10:00:00.0"

3)now , you have to do things,
    a) use split_apart to extract 10:00:00.0
    b) concat the extracted part with "2018-11-12"
so now you can get values in the format "2018-11-12 10:00:00.0"

4)Now the result of previous stepcan be casted as a timestamp

5)Use the select [column names col1,2,3,..],(cast (concat("2018-11-12",split_apart(col,delim,index)))as timestamp) to insert data into original table from temporary table